# how can i use jsf tag autocomplete in java project

Tags: jsf, tags

```
i'm using eclipse luna and the project used maven, there is a web project and it depends on some java modules, and there are some jsf page (.xhtml) in java modules.
```

the jsf tag in the web project can be aotucomepleted but not autocomplemte in the java projects.
i tried this "Window > Preferences > General > Content Types > Text > JSP > Add (xhtml)" but not work.
and i installed jboss tools plugins,it does not work too.
how can i use jsf tag autocomplete in java project?

Answer (score 0):

Check your Eclipse settings in

> Windows menu -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content assist

By default the autocomplete happens with ctrl+space.

Comment: it worked in web project but not in the java project(the web project dependent on). not the reason of that setting.I clicked 'ctr+space' and 'alt+\' it not work